# Determine whether the function is Lebesgue measurable

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Here's the full problem:

> Let $\mathcal{N} \subset [0,1]$ be a non-measurable set. Determine whether the function
>   $$f(x) = \left\{
>      \begin{array}{lr}
>        -x & : x \in \mathcal{N}\\
>        x & : x \notin \mathcal{N}
>      \end{array}
>    \right.$$
>   is measurable.

Here is what I've been thinking. We know that the definition of a measurable function entails that we can map any interval back to our domain and that it must then be measurable, which will imply $f \in \mathcal{M}$, where $\mathcal{M}$ denotes the set containing all measurable sets. What we'll ultimately be mapping back, I think, is
$$f^{-1}(\mathcal{N}), f^{-1}(\mathcal{N^c})$$
which implies we're mapping back
$$f^{-1}(\mathcal{N \cup N^c})=f^{-1}([0,1]) \in \mathcal{M}$$
so that means $f \in \mathcal{M}$.

Now my question: was this even remotely correct? I'm very new to Lebesgue measure, so this problem has been hurting. A friend and I were discussing this earlier, and we both agreed that it may not be this simple, so any feedback would be much obliged!

**EDIT**: Here is the way my professor constructed a non-measurable set for us:

> **Non-measurable set**
>
> Consider a set $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and recall that an equivalence relation partitions $E$ into equivalence classes $[x]=\{z:z\sim x\}$, i.e
>
> $$E=\bigcup_{i}[x]\;\;\;,\;\;[x]\cap [y] = \emptyset$$
>   $$\implies z\; s.t \; z\sim x,\; z\sim y \implies y\sim x,\;but\;then\;[x]=[y]$$
>
> Now suppose $E=[0,1]$ and say $x\sim y$ if $x-y \in \mathbb{Q}$ (this is an equivalence relation). Then,
>   $$[0,1]=\bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R \setminus Q}} E_{\alpha}$$
>   where $E_{\alpha}=[x_{\alpha}]$ and $\alpha$ is clearly uncountable. Now define $\mathcal{N}=\bigcup\{x_{\alpha}\}$. By transfinite induction, we establish that $\mathcal{N}\subset [0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by $f \in \mathcal{M}$?

You noted correctly that you have to decide wether $f^{-1}(I)$ is measurable for every interval $I \subset \Bbb{R}$.

As the definition of $f$ involves a **nonmeasurable** set, probably, $f$ will **not** be measurable (this is no rigorous argument, we just want to decide if we want to prove $f$ to be measurable or nonmeasurable).

So you need to choose $I$ correctly to ensure that $f^{-1}(I)$ is **not** measurable.

Attention: Spoilers below!

> You already know that $N$ is not measurable, so try to get something like $f^{-1}(I) = N$.

$ $

> Hint: It might be useful to consider $I = (0,\infty)$.

Comment: Sorry if my responses sound silly, but so what you're saying in the second spoiler is that for $\mathcal{N^c}$, choosing $I=(0,\infty)$ will be sufficient? Or that is but once of the cases we want to look at?
$$\\$$
When I say $f \in \mathcal{M}$, I'm simply saying $f$ is measurable

Comment: Also, $I$ intersects $\mathcal{N}$, so won't there arise issues there? I guess that would be the point, as this would then show us non-measurability, right?
$$\\$$
Thank you for your answer by the way. Though my confusion is still overpowering me, your answer has got me really thinking

Comment: Why do you think that there will be an issue if $I$ intersects $N$?
$$
\qquad
$$
One problem for me is that you do not clearly indicate the set on which $f$ is defined (hopefully $[0,1]$?).
$$
\qquad
$$
If this is the case, then $f(x) \geq 0$ for $x \notin N$ (right?). What is the case for $x \in N$?

Comment: I was quite tired when I posted this and went to bed shortly after, so my worry about the intersection was a tired concern (I realize the concern is not necessary).

The problem never gave us what we were defined on, but since $\mathcal{N} \subset [0,1]$, I think the assumption is safe. I will put a description of what my professor describing our Non-measurable set as.

In regards $f(x)\geq 0 \;\forall\;x\notin N$, for the case of $x \in \mathcal{N}$, we'll of course have $f(x)<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did this problem.

Let $f$ be described as above. $f$ is a measurable function if, for every $I$, $f^{-1} (I)$ is measurable. Now, what $f$ does is, is to separate out the points in $N$ from those not in $N$, by sending the ones not in $N$ to their negative values, while fixing the ones in $N$. So by taking the inverse of any $I$ of the form $(0,a), a > 1$, we'd have that $f^{-1}(I)=f^{-1}((0,1] \cup (1, a))=N \cup \emptyset=N$. This works since we decomposed $I$ into disjoint sets. Since $N$ is not measurable, clearly for this choice of $I$, we have an unmeasurable set, so $f$ cannot be measurable.

Not sure if this is 100% correct, but this was my reasoning.